# Maximum number of $0.5$ cm diameter circles that can fit in a $5$ cm $\times$ $5$ cm square

Tags: geometry

This is an aptitude question which looked simpler to me than it actually is and got me stuck. The question asks:

> What is the maximum number of cylindrical pencils of $0.5$ cm diameter that can be stood in a square shaped stand of $5$ cm $\times$ $5$ cm cross-section?

I am aware of hexagonal packing but i really don't know how to get the answer which says it should be $105$ pencils.

**EDIT**

A link to this question already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607979/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-pencil-that-can-be-stood-in-this-stand) found later.

Comment: One boring suggestion is to make the numbers more convenient---say, take the pencils to all have diameter 1 and the square to be 10-by-10.

Comment: @Semiclassical Still it doesn't help to get to the answer.

Comment: Try 6 rows of 10 and 5 rows of 9.

Comment: The given answer is actually wrong! A (nonhexagonal) packing of 106 pencils is known. ([See here](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/d9.html))

Comment: One generic remark: It is straightforward enough to give a configuration with 105 pencils. It is another matter entirely to show that this is the best one can do. (And, according to MJD, it's not actually the best.)

Comment: @Semiclassical  I drew in some detail for the 106 construction and added that to my answer. It really does work, just a little hard to understand without drawing in some detail in an expanded hexagon grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider lining one side of the box with 10 pencils. Then you place 9 pencils 'in between' each of the 10. The total height of these two rows, with pencil diameter $d=0.5$ is
$$\frac{d}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}d + \frac{d}{2}$$

Therefore the height of $n+1$ rows will be

$$\frac{d}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}dn + \frac{d}{2}$$ 
So you want 
$$\frac{d}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}dn + \frac{d}{2} \leq 5 \implies n\leq (\frac{5}{d} - 1)\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} = 10.39$$
therefore $n=10$ and you can fill $n+1 = 11$ rows like this, with $6$ having 10 pencils and $5$ having 9, giving $(5)(9) + (6)(10) = 105$ pencils. Note that this is NOT a proof that 105 is maximal, but we do have it is larger than the easier 100 pencil approach

Answer (score 3):

Later, decided to check the 106 construction, which really does work. The point is that **the circle inside a hexagon is slightly smaller**; in the drawing below, the indicated portion with four circles drawn in the corners is 10 units high, but is just $2 \sqrt 3 + 1 \approx 4.4641$ units wide. Meanwhile, it contains 48 circles, three columns 10 each, then two columns between at 9 circles each. Place another one of these next to it. So far, exact width is $4 \sqrt 3 + 2 \approx 8.9282.$ Finally, add a single column of ten circles, exact width $1.$ The full total width is $4 \sqrt 3 + 3 \approx 9.9282.$  The construction is shown in the lower left of [DIAGRAMS](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/d9.html)   [LARGER DIAGRAM](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/csq106.html)

[image]

There you go, 6 rows of 10 and 5 rows of 9, 60+45 = 105

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using Pythagorean theorem one finds the center of each row is $\sqrt{.5^2-.25^2}=.43cm$ apart with half a diameter of .25cm extra on top and bottom row. This means there are 11 rows with 10 on top row, 9 on second row, 10 on third row, etc. This means there are 6*10+5*9=105 total pencils.

Comment: must be non equilateral as I get 0.87 cm